# Как сделать редирект в nginx следующей чпу на новый url

Tags: nginx, rewrite, qregexp

Как сделать редирект (перенаправление) с этого адреса

```
https://sitename.local/users/?show_person&id=14906
```

на этот

```
https://sitename.local/newusers/14906/
```

с помощью nginx rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
location ~* /users {
    if ($args ~* "^show_person&id=(\d+)") {
        set $id $1;
        set $args "";
        rewrite ^.*$ /newusers/$id/ permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: @АлександрГалушко пожалуйста) Если можно отметьте вопрос решенным.